# Arduino Leonardo board - not running or appearing a USB on external power

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I've got an Leonardo board, it seems to be official, in that it has the Arduino branding and Made In Italy on the bottom.

However I cannot get anything to run with external power supply. Everything when powered via the USB from the computer runs fine. As soon as I use any sort of external power, and I've tried both the barrel jack with 4x AA batteries, 6x AA batteries, 9v square battery and a Shield with 2x 3.7v lithium batteries - it turns on but doesn't do anything - the USB device doesn't even appear to the computer at all unless I pull the external power out again.

Is this a faulty board? Do I need to change the jumper arrangement on the board so it'll run with external power?

Comment: I have just tested all combinations of power plugging and unplugging on my Leonardo. No problem with anything.

Comment: And what "jumper arrangement" are you on about? There's no jumpers on a Leonardo.

Comment: The ICSP section - I thought it might have something to do with it. I guess i've just got a dud board then. It's a Leonardo R3 by the way.

Comment: The ICSP is a header for a connector, not for jumpers! This question is related to your previous question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/60405/leonardo-always-on-power-status-remains-between-computer-reboots With a new question please show us also the sketch. I think a arduino board with seperated usb-serial chip and removed the reset via the dtr signal is better for your project. But I don't know the ideal combination that can do it all. You are in uncharted waters.

Comment: @Jot I think this board would be idea if it would work as obviously Majenkos does when you plug in power. As there are no settings or code related to this, I can only come to the conclusion there is a fault on this board.

Comment: I just grabbed an unregulated power supply of 12v and measured 18v. Please show a sketch that we can try, tell us what kind of power supply you use.

Comment: I was just testing with Blink. You get the CDC/ACM endpoint regardless, so enumeration can be tested and the blinking confirms constant sketch execution.

Comment: I think key to my sketch is that it's working over USB-HID - it's that connection which is never made when powering externally - it doesn't appear to the computer at all. As soon as I pull the external power it connects to the computer as a HID device.

Comment: Still fine if I add `Keyboard.h` and `Keyboard.begin()` to Blink. Enumerates fine and creates a HID input device every time - with or without external power, with external power added first, or USB power added first. All combinations are fine.

Comment: I am testing it and everything is working as it should be. Can you give more information? Do you know how old the leonardo board is and which bootloader is on it? What kind of power supply? What is your sketch?

Comment: Also what version of the IDE and boards package?

Comment: by USB device not appearing you mean  the virtual com port or a HID device?

Comment: 4xAA won't work as the VIN voltage must be greater than 6.6V to get precedence over the USB voltage. Did you check the polarity? The middle contact is positive, the surrounding contact is GND (negative).

Comment: @Pylon While a voltage lower than 6.6V will cause the USB's P-fet to get turned on when it's not desirable. It won't affect the operation of the sketch at all. Worst case scenario the computer will disable the USB port completely to isolate the external power. And it would alert you to that fact (Windows would pop up a bubble, linux / OS X would put it in dmesg, etc).

Comment: I tried with my Leonardo Microboard and the sketch runs just fine - so for whatever reason there's a fault on the Leonardo R3 board. Makes things a bit more annoying as i'll have to solder onto the micro board to complete the project instead of just using the shield, but supplying 5v from the shield to the micro works fine.